# How to load existing content in print.loadData in android studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to load the existing content from view functionality, when I'm click the "print" button.

My view/generate PDF code is :

```
private void createPdf(String id) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

        File pdfFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "pdfdemo");
        //File pdfFolder = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "pdfdemo");
        if (!pdfFolder.exists()) {
            pdfFolder.mkdirs();
            Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Pdf Directory created"+pdfFolder);
        }

        //Create time stamp
        Date date = new Date() ;
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(date);

        File myFile = new File(pdfFolder +"/"+ timeStamp + ".pdf");

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

        //Step 1
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 36, 36);

        //Step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);

        //Step 3
        document.open();



        // add image
        Drawable d = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.na);
        BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
        Bitmap bmp = bitDw.getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            image.scaleToFit(100,100);

            // image.setAbsolutePosition( 0,180);
            image.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 3});
        table.addCell(image);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        Font green = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 20, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.GREEN);
        Chunk redText = new Chunk("NATIONAL AGRO FOUNDATION", green);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        p.add(redText);
        cell.addElement(p);
        Font black = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Chunk text2 = new Chunk("LABORATARY SERVICES DIVISION", black);
        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph();
        p2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        p2.add(text2);
        cell.addElement(p2);
        Font black2 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Chunk text3 = new Chunk("Tharamani, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600113", black2);
        Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph();
        p3.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        p3.add(text3);
        cell.addElement(p3);
        Font black3 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Chunk text4 = new Chunk("Phone: 044 2254 2803", black3);
        Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph();
        p4.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        p4.add(text4);
        cell.addElement(p4);


        cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);

        table.addCell(cell);

        document.add(table);

        Font black4 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 15, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Chunk text5 = new Chunk("TEST REPORT:-", black4);
        Paragraph p5 = new Paragraph();
        p5.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        p5.add(text5);
        document.add(p5);
        document.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );

        dbHandler = new DBHandler(context);
        dbs = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM kiosk_trn_tsoil WHERE soil_gid = "+id;

        Cursor cursor = dbs.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {

            PdfPTable tbl = new PdfPTable(4);

            tbl.setWidthPercentage(100);
            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Report No"));
            cell2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell2.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);

            tbl.addCell(cell2);
            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cursor.getString(3)));

            tbl.addCell(cell2);
            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sample Description"));
            cell2.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            cell2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            tbl.addCell(cell2);

            cell2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));

            tbl.addCell(cell2);
            document.add(tbl);

            PdfPTable tb2 = new PdfPTable(4);

            tb2.setWidthPercentage(100);
            PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Report Date"));
            cell3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell3.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);


            tb2.addCell(cell3);
            cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cursor.getString(2)));

            tb2.addCell(cell3);
            cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sample Drawan By"));
            cell3.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            cell3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            tb2.addCell(cell3);

            cell3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("FARMER"));

            tb2.addCell(cell3);
            document.add(tb2);

            PdfPTable tb3 = new PdfPTable(4);

            tb3.setWidthPercentage(100);
            PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Unique Lab Report No"));
            cell4.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell4.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);

            tb3.addCell(cell4);
            cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cursor.getString(8)));

            tb3.addCell(cell4);
            cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customers Reference"));
            cell4.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            cell4.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            tb3.addCell(cell4);

            cell4.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(sharedpreferences.getString("fcode","")));

            tb3.addCell(cell4);
            document.add(tb3);

            PdfPTable tb5 = new PdfPTable(4);

            tb5.setWidthPercentage(100);
            PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Lab Id"));
            cell5.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell5.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);

            tb5.addCell(cell5);
            cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cursor.getString(9)));

            tb5.addCell(cell5);
            cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sample Received On"));
            cell5.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            cell5.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            tb5.addCell(cell5);

            cell5.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cursor.getString(10)));

            tb5.addCell(cell5);
            document.add(tb5);

            PdfPTable tb6 = new PdfPTable(4);

            tb6.setWidthPercentage(100);
            PdfPCell cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Analysis Started On"));
            cell6.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell6.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);

            tb6.addCell(cell6);
            cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cursor.getString(11)));

            tb6.addCell(cell6);
            cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Analysis Completed On"));
            cell6.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            cell6.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            tb6.addCell(cell6);

            cell6.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cursor.getString(12)));

            tb6.addCell(cell6);
            document.add(tb6);

            PdfPTable tb7 = new PdfPTable(4);
            tb7.setWidthPercentage(100);

            PdfPCell cell7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sample Id"));
            cell7.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell7.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);

            tb7.addCell(cell7);
            cell7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));

            tb7.addCell(cell7);
            cell7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
            cell7.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            cell7.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            tb7.addCell(cell7);

            cell7.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cursor.getString(5)));

            tb7.addCell(cell7);
            document.add(tb7);
            tm = cursor.getString(13);

        }


        document.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
        PdfPTable tablel = new PdfPTable(5);
        tablel.setWidthPercentage(100);
// Header
        PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("S No"));
        PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Parameter"));
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Unit"));
        PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Results"));
        PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Test Method"));
        cell1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
        cell2.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
        cell3.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
        cell4.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
        cell5.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
        tablel.addCell(cell1);

        tablel.addCell(cell2);
        tablel.addCell(cell3);
        tablel.addCell(cell4);
        tablel.addCell(cell5);

// Data
//        String selectQuery2 = "SELECT  * FROM kiosk_trn_tsoilparameter";
//
//        Cursor c = dbs.rawQuery(selectQuery2, null);

        Cursor c= dbs.query("kiosk_trn_tsoilparameter", new String[]{"soilparam_gid","soilparam_soil_gid","soil_parameter","soil_uom","soil_results"
                }, "soilparam_soil_gid" + "=? COLLATE NOCASE",
                new String[]{id}, null, null, null, null);
        int i = 1;
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String group = String.valueOf(i);
                cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(group));
                tablel.addCell(cell1);


                String selectQuery3 = "SELECT  * FROM core_mst_tmaster WHERE master_rowid = "+c.getString(2);
                Cursor cursor2 = dbs.rawQuery(selectQuery3, null);
                if(cursor2.moveToNext())
                {
                    Log.e("VVV",""+cursor2.getString(2));
                    Cursor cursor3= dbs.query("core_mst_tmastertranslate", new String[]{"master_name"
                            }, "mastertranslate_master_code" + "=? COLLATE NOCASE",
                            new String[]{cursor2.getString(2)}, null, null, null, null);

                    if(cursor3.moveToNext())
                    {
                        String machine = cursor3.getString(0);
                        cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(machine));
                        tablel.addCell(cell2);
                    }

                }

                String selectQuery4 = "SELECT  * FROM core_mst_tmaster WHERE master_rowid = "+c.getString(3);
                Cursor cursor4 = dbs.rawQuery(selectQuery4, null);
                if(cursor4.moveToNext())
                {
                    Log.e("VVV",""+cursor2.getString(2));
                    Cursor cursor3= dbs.query("core_mst_tmastertranslate", new String[]{"master_name"
                            }, "mastertranslate_master_code" + "=? COLLATE NOCASE",
                            new String[]{cursor4.getString(2)}, null, null, null, null);

                    if(cursor3.moveToNext())
                    {
                        String machine = cursor3.getString(0);
                        cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(machine));
                        tablel.addCell(cell3);
                    }

                }
                String machine = c.getString(4);
                cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(machine));
                tablel.addCell(cell4);

                String machine2 = tm;
                cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(machine2));
                tablel.addCell(cell4);

                i++;
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        document.add(tablel);

        Drawable d2 = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.newfooter);
        BitmapDrawable bitDw2 = ((BitmapDrawable) d2);
        Bitmap bmp2 = bitDw2.getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream2= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream2);
        Image image2 = null;
        try {
            image2 = Image.getInstance(stream2.toByteArray());
            image2.scaleToFit(800,100);

            // image.setAbsolutePosition( 0,180);
            image2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        document.add(image2);
        document.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );

        Font black5 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 15, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Chunk text6 = new Chunk("Notes:-", black5);
        Paragraph p6 = new Paragraph();
        p6.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        p6.add(text6);
        document.add(p6);


        document.add(new Paragraph(". The above report is applicable only to the sample received and tested. "));
        document.add(new Paragraph(". The tested samples will not be retained after 30 days from the date of issue of the test report."));
        document.add(new Paragraph(". Perishable samples will be destroyed after testing. "));
        document.add(new Paragraph(". Any request for retesting will not be considered after 30 days from the date of issue of the report. "));
        document.add(new Paragraph(". Our report shall not be reproduced wholly or in part and cannot be used as evidence in the court of law . "));
        document.add(new Paragraph(". Our report in full or part shall not be used for any advertising media without our prior written approval. "));
        //Step 5: Close the document
        document.close();
        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();

        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(myFile), "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
```

My Print button code is

```
private void doPrint() {

    WebView print=prepPrintWebView("Web page");

    //print.loadUrl("https://commonsware.com/Android");
    print.loadData("Hello World!!!!","text/html","utf-8");

}
```

In the above code the content "Hello World!!!" is displaying fine when I clicked the "Print" button, but I need the existing view content to gets display when I click the "Print" button. I tried to pass the view code in the place of "Hello World" but am getting the actual code instead of getting tables and images.

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve my issue...plz

Comment: I tried to pass HTML content and it is working fine, but I dont know how to pass existing code for print. `String customHtml = "<html><body><h1>Hello, AbhiAndroid</h1>" +
            "<h1>Heading 1</h1><h2>Heading 2</h2><h3>Heading 3</h3>" +
            "<p>This is a sample paragraph of static HTML In Web view</p>" +
            "</body></html>";
    WebView print=prepPrintWebView("Web page");

    //print.loadUrl("https://commonsware.com/Android");
    print.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");`